# How to get JSON schema from Swagger URL

Tags: c#, .net, json, swagger

Tech Stack

- .Net core 2.0 API
- MarkLogic

We are using nosql database and we get output from MarkLogic API, we send it as it is in response.

That means, user will never get a full response model structure as a output for given result as some elements will be present in document(s) and few will not be part of document(s).

So in this case, from client side, user will like to see full model structure which is available as a part of model structure in Swagger.

So question is, how to get full model structure thru swagger URL, something like
https://url/swagger/v1/model.json

Comment: Are your model json files stored in MarkLogic?

Comment: Hello Saša, Thanks for your reply. No, MarkLogic we have xml files, we are converting it & sending it in JSON response.

Answer (score 1):

I think the first part of this challenge is "where do the swagger files live".  You state in response to Saša that they are not in MarkLogic. They would need to be published somewhere for consumption.

*If you were to store your swagger files in MarkLogic*, then  you could consider different options in returning them to the client:

- Retrieve them using MarkLogic's document endpoint:

  If you had predictable uris like /reference/swagger/my-model-v1.json, then the standard OOTB document endpoint would work fine. Otherwise, you could use the search endpoint for more complex needs or use a http rewriter to tune the desired URI.
- Rest Extension for swagger models:
  Based on your sample URI, you could write an extension as a swagger service to return what is needed.
- [optionally] Return as part of the payload

  It sounds like you are already transforming your content on the way out (intercepting it in a transform from search or a custom rest extension (I infer this because you state that you are converting to JSON when sending the content). Since you are already dynamically creating JSON on the way out, you could use this as a hook to offer the model as part of the results where people could get content, model or both.